# java.lang.illegalargumentexception: 'couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority ABC.mobile.app.fileprovider'

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I am working on MAUI app. when i am click on attachment png, it should open file (pdf/image) but it will give an error

> java.lang.illegalargumentexception: 'couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority ABC.mobile.app.fileprovider' maui

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem or a basic demo so that we can test on our side?